# How to convert a dictionary of tuples into a dictionary of lists (Python)?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I'm new to Python (and programming in general), but I have a dictionary with the keys being tuples, and I want to make a new dictionary with those same keys as lists.

here's what I mean:

I have:

```
d = {("apple", "banana", "pear", "pineapple"):24, 
("banana", "pineapple", "apple", "pear"):17,
("pineapple", "pear", "banana", "apple"):10,
("apple", "pineapple", "banana", "pear"):16}
```

I want:

```
new_d = {["apple", "banana", "pear", "pineapple"]:24, 
["banana", "pineapple", "apple", "pear"]:17, 
["pineapple", "pear", "banana", "apple"]:10, 
["apple", "pineapple", "banana", "pear"]:16}
```

is there a simple way to do this using for loops and if statements?

Comment: A list can't be the key of a dictionary entry.

Comment: what's the end goal here?  Perhaps there is an alternative approach that will solve your current problem (as I don't see what the problem is).

Answer (score 7):

lists are not hashable and therefore cannot be keys in a dictionary.

Why do you want your keys to be lists? If you're currently calling a function

```
expect_iterable_of_lists(d.keys())
```

, you can simply combine `map` and `list`:

```
expect_iterable_of_lists(map(list, d.keys()))
```

Comment: It would be more correct to say that lists aren't *hashable* and therefore can't be used with a hash-table based dictionary.  You can use mutable keys in a dictionary, you just have to make sure the mutations don't affect the ability to find a key later.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by others, it likely isn't a good idea to use lists as dictionary keys.

If that is what you really need though, it isn't hard to add hashability to lists:

```
>>> class List(list):
        def __hash__(self):
            return hash(tuple(self))

>>> d = {("apple", "banana", "pear", "pineapple"):24, 
("banana", "pineapple", "apple", "pear"):17,
("pineapple", "pear", "banana", "apple"):10,
("apple", "pineapple", "banana", "pear"):16}

>>> new_d = {List(k):v for k, v in d.items()}
>>> new_d
{['banana', 'pineapple', 'apple', 'pear']: 17,
 ['apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'pineapple']: 24, 
 ['pineapple', 'pear', 'banana', 'apple']: 10, 
 ['apple', 'pineapple', 'banana', 'pear']: 16}
```

This code will achieve your goal of using a list a key and it will work just fine as long as you don't mutate the list (dicts based on hash tables don't work well with mutable keys).  If you do need to mutate the keys, you'll need an alternative dictionary implementation that doesn't rely on hashing (an [association list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_list) for example).